# matrix operators with element-wise calculations

Tags: matlab

If I have [1 2 3] and I need to respectively multiply it by [2 3 4] to make the array [1*2 2*3 3*4], how do I do that?

I can't seem to do [1 2 3]*[2 3 4] = [1*2 2*3 3*4]

My actual issue is:

```
At=sum(abs([1 2 3].*exp(i.*[4 5 6])))
```

Tried rewriting it with a bsxfun inside the sum, but I get an error about not enough elements. It works with [1x1] and [1x1], but I tried with [1x6000] and [1x6000] and AT is equal one value.  Not sure if the sum there is a good idea.

How would I go about performing the above operation so that the 1 and 4 are affected together, the 2 and 5 are affected together, and the 3 and 6 are affected together such that 'At' gives a 3x1 or 1x3 array?

Thank you so much!

EDIT: Alright so it seems that the exponential function "works".

What doesn't work is that it either adds everything together or creates twice as many solutions as I need.

If I feed it this kind of info:

```
 A1=[1 2]

 A2=[1 2]

 p=[0.1 0.2]

 p=[0.1 0.2]

>> [At] = somme_signaux([A1 A2],[p1 p2]);
>> At
At =    1.0000    2.0000    1.0000    2.0000
```

I'm going to get 4 answers without the sum. I need 2 answers (the first and second answer added together (1+2), and the third and fourth answer added together(1+2)) into a 2 by 1 matrix.

Comment: Obviously you get just one value when summing over a vector with just the vector as the input for `sum` - this is how it works. I don't understand what you want to get. Would you please update your question to include a demonstration of the expected inputs and the expected outputs. Please show exactly the values of **`A1, A2, At`** that you want to get (start by adding the correct `At` to the first example) for inputs of different shapes (column vectors, row vectors 2d arrays or whatever it is you need).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really get your issue? `.*` can be used for element-wise multiplication, i.e.

```
>> [1 2 3].*[2 3 4]

ans =

     2     6    12
```

Also, the code with the complex exponential works for me.

Comment: >> At=sum(abs([1 2 3].*exp(i.*[4 5 6])))

At =

     6

Comment: I need At to be 3 numbers, not a single one.

Comment: What do you expect when taking the sum? You have a sum of an array of three values.